Wordpress post date (seconds) displayed in a negative value
I'm using DirectoryPress plugin with WordPress and have a problem with the post date display.
The problem is that when a person adds a listing, the time (seconds specifically) is displayed in a negative value:

Here is the code I am using:
$time = strtotime( $listing->post->post_date );
echo '<div class="publish_date">'.directorypress_time_ago($time).'</div>';

What could be the problem?
